# Get the password for x509Certificate C# bouncy castle

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, self-signed, x509certificate2

Hi I use the attached code to create x509certificate with bouncy-castle dll
how can i get the Certificate password?

```
private static X509Certificate2 GenerateCertificate(string certName)
    {
        var keypairgen = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
        keypairgen.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(new CryptoApiRandomGenerator()), 1024));

        var keypair = keypairgen.GenerateKeyPair();

        var gen = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();

        var CN = new X509Name("CN=" + certName);
        var SN = BigInteger.ProbablePrime(120, new Random());

        gen.SetSerialNumber(SN);
        gen.SetSubjectDN(CN);
        gen.SetIssuerDN(CN);
        gen.SetNotAfter(DateTime.MaxValue);
        gen.SetNotBefore(DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0)));
        gen.SetSignatureAlgorithm("MD5WithRSA");
        gen.SetPublicKey(keypair.Public);

        var newCert = gen.Generate(keypair.Private);

        return new X509Certificate2(DotNetUtilities.ToX509Certificate((Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate)newCert));
    }
```

Comment: Unless you are going to save the certificate to an external file, there is no password involved.

Comment: I want to know the password because I want to save it to a file and use it later.

Comment: when you call the method to save it to a file, that method will ask you for a password.

Comment: thanks for the help!